# How to check whether childnode exist or not in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to check in xslt whether an existing child node exist or not. My if statement is unable to read the existing child node.

Here is my if statement:

```
 <xsl:if test="following-sibling::Blogs/IDs">
         <xsl:for-each select="IDs">
           <xsl:for-each select="Blog[@CategoryId = current()/@id]">
             <li style="display: list-item; opacity: 1;">
               <div class="blog-item">
                 <h3 class="blog-h3">
                 </h3>
                 <span>
                   <a href="" target="_blank">
                     <xsl:value-of select="@UserName"></xsl:value-of>
                   </a>
                 </span>
                 <span>
                   <a href="/Listing/profile/15/udal-bharti" target="_blank">
                     <xsl:value-of select="@ReplyCount"></xsl:value-of>
                   </a>
                 </span>
                 <span>
                   <a href="/Listing/profile/15/udal-bharti" target="_blank">
                     <xsl:value-of select="@Title"></xsl:value-of>
                   </a>
                 </span>
                 <span>
                   <a href="/Listing/profile/15/udal-bharti" target="_blank">
                     <xsl:value-of select="@CatName"></xsl:value-of>
                   </a>
                 </span>
                 <span>
                   <a href="/Listing/profile/15/udal-bharti" target="_blank">
                     <xsl:value-of select="@VisitCount"></xsl:value-of>
                   </a>
                 </span>
                 <p>
                   <xsl:value-of select="@ShortDescription"></xsl:value-of>
                 </p>
               </div>
             </li>
           </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:if>
```

Here is my xml:

```
enter code here

 <Blogs><IDs Id="1"></Blogs>
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you probably just want to do `<xsl:if test="IDs">`, but it really depends on what your current context is when the `xsl:if` is evaluated. Can you give a more fully sample of XSLT (i.e the template match), and possibly more or your XML too? Thanks!

Comment: OK i edit my code..u see ..